# I'm trying to create an admin "login" on batch and it just closes the cmd

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make an "admin" login and it isn't working.

```
@echo off
title RPG BETA
color 0b

set /p player=Welcome to Xero, what's your name?:
if %player% == Admin goto admin

:intro
echo Hello %player%!
pause
goto start

:admin
set /p password:What is the admin password?:
if %password% == Insertanypassword goto true
if %password not insertanypassword goto false

:true
cls
echo Welcome, Admin!
set /p af=Would you like to enable admin features?[y/n]:
if %af% == y goto true1
if %af% == n goto start

:true1
cls
set CPU=20
set CPUN=Scorpion
set CPUD=3
set gun=9999999
set gund=9999999
set playerh=9999999
goto fight

:start
cls
echo In the distant future, the world was on the brink of destrucion.
timeout 3 >nul
echo In the midst of the wasteland, a single man, named %player%, will overcome the odds
pause
goto BFight

:BFight
cls
set CPU=20
set CPUN=Scorpion
set CPUD=3
set gun=1
set gund=10
set playerh=20
:Fight
cls
if %CPU% leq 0 goto win
if %playerh% == 0 goto lose
cls
echo You encounter a %CPUN%!

echo                            %CPUN% Health: %CPU%
echo.
echo                            Your Health: %playerh%

echo [1]Shoot (%gund% damage) (%gun%)
echo [2]Punch (3 damage)
echo [3]Flee

set /p fp=What do you do?
if %fp% == 1 goto gun
if %fp% == 2 goto punch
if %fp% == 3 goto flee

:gun
cls
if '%gun%'=='0' goto egun
set /a gun = gun - 1
echo You fire at the %CPUN%
timeout 4 >nul
echo It hits!
set /a CPU = CPU - gund
pause
goto cpufightp

:punch
cls
echo You punch the %CPUN%
timeout 4 >nul
echo It hits!
set /a CPU = CPU - 3
pause
goto cpufightp

:egun
echo You have no bullets!
pause
goto Fight

:cpufightp
if %CPU% leq 0 goto win
cls
echo                            %CPUN% Health: %CPU%
echo.
echo                            Your Health: %playerh%
pause
cls
goto cpufight

:cpufight
cls
echo The %CPUN% Attacks!
timeout 4 >nul
echo It hits!
set /a playerh = playerh - CPUD
pause
goto fight

:flee
goto losef

:losef
cls echo you have fled
pause
goto suggestion

:lose
cls
echo You died
pause
cls

:win
cls
echo Congradulations, %player%! You win!
pause
cls

:suggestion
set /p suggest=What should I add to Xero?:
echo %player%: %suggest% >> xerosuggest.word
```

Whenever I type in "Admin" instead of going to the password screen, it just closes cmd, can anyone tell me why? i have experimented with ''s and other commands but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with respect to your specific issue is a typo.

You have:

```bat
set /p password:What is the admin password?:
```

Instead of:

```bat
Set /P "password=What is the admin password?: "
```

The doublequotes are simply good practice, your error was quite clearly that you used a <kbd>:</kbd> instead of  a <kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: the : was there not as code but as like "what would you like to do?:(user answer)